# Connection to Oracle Autonomous Database using sqlplus without wallet

Tags: oracle, sqlplus

I'm trying to connect to Oracle Autonomous Database using EZ CONNECT string: user/password@host:port/service_name

I have configured the access from the IP addresses I need to connect and set mTLS as not required:

[image: Oracle Autonomous Database Network Settings]

As a result, I can successfully connect to the database when I use the wallet downloaded from the console.

But if I try to connect to the DB using EZ CONNECT string, I get the following error:

```
sqlplus -l user/password@tcp://adb.us-sanjose-1.oraclecloud.com:1521/service_name_high.adb.oraclecloud.com

SQL*Plus: Release 19.0.0.0.0 - Production on Wed May 25 00:19:38 2022
Version 19.8.0.0.0

Copyright (c) 1982, 2020, Oracle.  All rights reserved.

ERROR:
ORA-12547: TNS:lost contact


SP2-0751: Unable to connect to Oracle.  Exiting SQL*Plus
```

Is it possible to connect to Autonomous Database using EZ CONNECT string? If yes, then what am I doing wrong?

**Update 1:**

I also tried to use a full connect string

```
sqlplus -l user/pass@'(description= (retry_count=20)(retry_delay=3)(address=(protocol=tcps)(port=1521)(host=adb.us-sanjose-1.oraclecloud.com))(connect_data=(service_name=xxxxxxx_high.adb.oraclecloud.com))(security=(ssl_server_dn_match=yes)(ssl_server_cert_dn="CN=adb.us-sanjose-1.oraclecloud.com, OU=Oracle ADB SANJOSE, O=Oracle Corporation, L=Redwood City, ST=California, C=US")))'
```

but then the connection fails with the following error `ORA-28759: failure to open file.`

I suspect that it's some security settings, but I can clearly see that my IP is enabled and since with the same security settings I can connect with mutual TLS and wallet, I don't understand where the problem might be.

Comment: It is not possible to connect without using the wallet.

Comment: Franck Pachot wrote an article how to do that easily: https://www.freelists.org/post/oracle-l/is-it-possible-to-use-and-oracle-wallet-w-ezconnect,4

Answer (score 1):

You can configure Autonomous to allow connection without a WALLET:

https://docs.oracle.com/en/cloud/paas/autonomous-database/adbsa/support-tls-mtls-authentication.html

(Which looks like you done that)

However you still need TCPS and not TCP:
https://docs.oracle.com/en/cloud/paas/autonomous-database/adbsa/connect-jdbc-thin-tls.html - and you need to pass the security part, which cannot be passed today in the short format (see connecting without a wallet).

PS: Autonomous Dedicated (ADB-D) allows connecting with pure TCP.

Comment: I was trying to use a full connect string `sqlplus -l user/pass@'(description= (retry_count=20)(retry_delay=3)(address=(protocol=tcps)(port=1521)(host=adb.us-sanjose-1.oraclecloud.com))(connect_data=(service_name=xxxxxxx_high.adb.oraclecloud.com))(security=(ssl_server_dn_match=yes)(ssl_server_cert_dn="CN=adb.us-sanjose-1.oraclecloud.com, OU=Oracle ADB SANJOSE, O=Oracle Corporation, L=Redwood City, ST=California, C=US")))'`, but then the connection fails with following error `ORA-28759: failure to open file`. Any advice here?

Comment: Have you set TNS_ADMIN and is there an SQLNET.ORA in your path? If that is the case, the sqlnet.ora will point to a wallet file, which the connection will try to use as you pointed to in via. sqlnet.ora.